# How to parse multiple html pages into a string?

Tags: php, html, parsing, file-get-contents

I'm trying to parse the code of multiple html pages into a string, to make like a buffer, and read this string in order to find a specific text that are input, everthing is ok, the only problem, is that I'm not able to load the pages into the string and read after.

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/';
$start = 0;
$end = 1120;

$counter = $start;
while ($counter <= $end) {

    /*** a link to search - add the counter value and html to the end of url ***/
    $link = "$url$counter.html";
    /*** get the links ***/
        $data = file_get_contents($link);
        $data = $data.$data;
//      echo $data;

    $counter = $counter + 15;

}
```

Could someone help me in this case?

Regards

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: Did you do any debugging? What are the results of `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to parse the DOM from multiple pages into a string? Like what sort of problem are you trying to solve? Surely there's a better way to do what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the HTML code into a string, and with this string read it multiple times, to get different informations. To not request all the pages again on each request, i'm trying to do like a buffer of the codes from all pages, and read it in the code.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from [**PHPQuery**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/). It allows you to search multiple pages and extract their DOM contents with code as simple as `pq('.class')->text()`.

Comment: $data = $data . $data?

Comment: $data = $data . $data?  - Adding the new value to the end of the old value.

Comment: Except you just overwrote it ... $data = file_get_contents($link);

Comment: No, not overwritten because when I print the $data, appears  2 or more pages but not all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/';
$start = 0;
$end = 1120;
$counter = $start;
$data="";
while ($counter <= $end) {
    $link = "$url$counter.html";
    $res = file_get_contents($link);
    If ($res!==false){
       $data .=$res;
    }
    $counter = $counter + 15;

}
```

Comment: A little explanation of the problem and solution would make this nice and complete.

Comment: That`s worked, but the string show undefined error when execute 200 pages buffer, maybe the string stay oversized?

Comment: don't think so string size limit is about 2GB